# Can you translate a birchat hamitzvah before doing the action?

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, hefsek-interruption

Can you translate a birchat hamitzvah before doing the action? I.e. for Channukah candles, can you say each bracha followed (or preceded) by its translation, and then light? What about for reading megillah? [trying to find examples that have more than one bracha]. What about for a deoreita?

Comment: If you already said the translation, the latter would likely be a berakha levatala.

Comment: @mevaqesh's comment sounds correct. Most brachot can be said in any language, and there is a general rule that one should not interrupt between the bracha and the performance of the mitzvah. So, it seems that the best option is to just say the translation.

Comment: @DanF The best option is just to say the Hebrew and understand it.

Comment: @DoubleAA src? Also, if you leave out the shem hashem in the translation, there wouldnt be an issue. Since it is unlikely that you said the shem hashem in translation, lets leave that aside.

Comment: @marisbest2 "God" or "Lord" or even "O Merciful One" works just fine in Berakhot. ("Hashem" might not, as it's not a name.)

Comment: Did the person saying the translation think they were saying a bracha in a different language? Or were they thinking that they are not making the bracha, but rather saying what the bracha means. That would make a world of difference, at least when saying the translation beforehand.

Comment: @DoubleAA, do brachot need kavanna? If so, and it's the kavanna of knowing what you're saying (and not just that you're doing the act), then if you translated each bracha non-literally, so that it's not matbea chachamim and therefore not a bracha levatala, then the translations could be seen as letzorech mitzvah and not an interruption. Does that sound right?

Comment: @josh No. Maybe you could look at the translation silently while reading the Hebrew or something (like an Artscroll interlinear Siddur), but there's still no justification for saying more stuff out loud

Answer (score 4):

Igrot Moshe (OC 3:8) forbids translating or explaining prayers in another language at a time when interruptions are forbidden.

Comment: Does he mention that saying the bracha in translation to begin, is OK? (I assume that it is.)

Comment: @DanF He doesn't discuss a time when interruptions aren't forbidden (such as before you've said a blessing), but I don't know why discussing Torah concepts would be problematic, though intentionally saying a blessing twice is definitely forbidden (known as Berakha Levatala).

Comment: האם אתה יכול לתת יותר בשר?